# Lazy loading with fade in

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-image

I'm looking for a way to lazy load images into a listview. Preferably a framework that also support image animations.

Is this available for Android?

I'm using API level 8 and up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [Android Query](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/). It has support for lazy loading of images.
As you can see in [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading), it also supports basic animations.

Example to lazy load with basic settings:

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
aq.id(your_imageview).image("your_image_url");
```

Example to lazy load an image with a fade in animation:

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
aq.id(your_imageview).image("your_image_url", true, true, 0, null, 0, AQuery.FADE_IN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/):

Without animations:

```
$.with(myView).image(url);
```

With fade-in animation:

```
$.with(myView).attr("alpha", 0.0f);
$.ajax(new AjaxOptions(url).type("GET").dataType("image").success(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        $.with(myView).val((Bitmap) params[0]).fadeIn();
    }
}));
```